# APR for a Loan Paid Off in Monthly Payments for 9 Months

Tags: loans, interest-rate, apr

Say a loan is issued for 9 months with $1000 principal and with a payment plan consisting of about $162.23 each month.  Does this loan have an APR of 46%?

Comment: Instead of asking a series of specific scenarios a better question is to ask how to calculate the APR given a number of payments, PV, FV and monthly payment

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: The question I linked to was answered in great detail. A TI BA35 calculator or similar finance calculator would be a great purchase.

Answer (score 0):

The monthly rate is 8.322 %, found by solving the equation below.

[image]

Giving an effective annual rate of `(1 + i)^12 - 1 = 1.60977 = 161 %`

or a nominal rate, compounded monthly of `i*12 = 0.998646 = 100 %`

Comment: Wouldn't it be 146% since we have 9 x 162.23 / 1000?